# List of best practices on structuring SharePoint 2010 solutions

Tags: visual-studio, feature, solution-package, best-practices

I am looking for good guidance on how to structure a SharePoint Solution including:

- Visual Studio Project Structure
- Features (how to separate features)
- Namespaces
- When to use multiple project containers

Are there any good articles, documentation or books on this subject?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are quite a few things to consider in organizing your structure, or else maintanance or understanding the code becomes a nightmare (even if you revisit after a few years).

A similar question was asked in an earlier best practices post.

Some rules I follow are:

1. Keep all projects in one folder
   ("Projects"), keep solutions in
   another folder ("Solutions"). That
   way you can have any solution use
   any projects, esp useful if you have
   common framework-type projects, Keep all the dependent assemblies separate.
2. Namespace should indicate the
   intrinsic functionality of the code,
   not company, not type not
   departments, nor something too generic or superfluous (Company.Data eg) . I have worked on
   projects where company names have
   changed and had to go thru some
   tedious refactors, but using company
   name seems to be the norm in .Net
   world. Sometimes makes sense,
   sometimes not. Refactoring is not
   simple in SP, as code references are
   in wsp, cdb, config files, webpart
   pages etc. Naming by project has less chances of changing names and external dependencies.
3. In anycase, the intrinsic
   functionality of the module never
   changes (order is always an order),
   so it is useful to have namespaces
   reflect that and put all order related stuff in it. Adding types to
   namespaces seems superfluous to me
   in most cases, but occasionally it is useful.
4. If your marketing webcontrol is
   generic enough and will be used by
   somebody else tomorrow, or your
   marketing is renamed or merged to
   "sales", you have a code that
   carries history.
5. With VisualWebParts, now webpart
   code and webcontrols are generated together by VS2010. So unless its a webcontrol all of its own without a webpart, may be you can have it a WebControls namespace.

In general, I have seen Functional namespacing makes it quicker to understand the overall relationship of different modules without having to worry about how it is implemented.

Comment: Regarding #2 and #3: There's a reason why "Company.Data.*" is "the norm in .Net world" (and I might add in Java world). You might not like it personally, but be careful before suggesting as best practice something that deviates from what everyone else is doing.

Answer (score 12):

If you read Vesa Juvonens super-article about SharePoint 2010 WebTemplates, [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119071517/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx), you will see how he organizes and names features and SPI's. It's a very good approach and it mmakes it very easy to locate SPI's and features in the (not so user-friendly when you have tons of SPI's) package and feature designer.

Answer (score 8):

- Project Structure - I'm still experimenting with different styles, though it seems to be the norm to split off artefacts (such as c# WebParts) atomically, and use project references to include a "release version" of that project into a SharePoint Project designed solely for Packaging. This prevents you from building half-finished and broken code and including that in the current build of the solution you are working on.
- Features will be separated by Scope, I personally don't think it's necessary to split up provisioning of columns, webparts, content types, etc... only gives the user more stuff to switch on.
- Namespaces - I tend to use ClientName.Division.Function.ArtefactType - so for example: Contoso.Marketing.Branding.WebControls for controls that are used specifically in a solution used only by the Marketing department of Contoso.

Project containers? Haven't used them yet. Slap me silly if I should read into them, still spending a lot of time on my current 2007 project :P

Answer (score 7):

Regarding namespaces: Microsoft has recommendations: [Namespace Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

I think that any .Net guidance that you can find is a really good start, since it's still a .Net project. You could look at the [Developing Application for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770300.aspx) from the Microsoft Patterns & Practices, which is more specific.

Answer (score 5):

The following link describes sharepoint 2010 project structure (VS project structure)
http://bitofthought.blogspot.in/2012/05/visual-studio-sharepoint-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

Victor Wilén did a pretty good writeup on the SharePoint project that I have found applicable in my work situtations.

The template was an output of a collaborative conference, held in London couple of years ago. THe creation of the template involved several Microsoft MVP's, including: Andrew Connell, Ben Robb, Eric Schupps, Matthew McDermott, Mirjam van Olst, Paul Schaeflein, Todd Carter and Waldek Mastykarz.

The template is available from:
http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/International-SharePoint-Conference-2012-wrapup.aspx

and 
http://spkbase.codeplex.com/